# Motivic Interpretation of Rationally Trivial Cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology, derived-algebraic-geometry, chow-groups, motivic-homotopy

The Chow groups are defined by taking groups of cycles modulo rationally trivial cycles. One then has a cycle class map to etale cohomology (over the base field), and for a number field, one expects this to be an isomorphism after tensoring appropriately.

On the other hand, there seems to be no clear way to study the rationally trivial cycles. Tomer Schlank has developed an stable etale homotopy obstruction, which can detect rationally trivial cycles, albeit only modulo two. Motivated also by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30396/derived-algebraic-geometry-and-chow-rings-chow-motives), I'm wondering if there might be anything motivic that could give access to these cycles.